# Get the index of the last occurrence of each string in an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array that is storing a large number of various names in string format. There can be duplicates.

```
     let myArray = ["Jim","Tristan","Robert","Lexi","Michael","Robert","Jim"]
```

In this case I do NOT know what values will be in the array after grabbing the data from a parse server. So the data imported will be different every time. Just a list of random names.

Assuming I don't know all the strings in the array I need to find the index of the last occurrence of each string in the array.

Example:

If this is my array....

```
    let myArray = ["john","john","blake","robert","john","blake"]
```

I want the last index of each occurrence so...

```
    blake = 5
    john = 4
    robert = 3
```

What is the best way to do this in Swift?

Normally I would just make a variable for each item possibility in the array and then increment through the array and count the items but in this case there are thousands of items in the array and they are of unknown values.

Comment: How would you do it? Tell us, and we'll tell you if that's the best approach or not ;)

Comment: Create a `[String:Int]` dictionary. `enumerate` the array and set the `index` as value for the key `element`. Eventually you have all names and their latest index respectively.

Comment: https://www.tutorialkart.com/swift-tutorial/get-array-size-count-in-swift/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array with elements and their indices:

```
zip(myArray, myArray.indices)
```

then `reduce` into a dictionary where keys are array elements and values are indices:

```
let result = zip(myArray, myArray.indices).reduce(into: [:]) { dict, tuple in
   dict[tuple.0] = tuple.1
}
```

(`myArray.enumerated()` returns offsets, not indices, but it would have worked here too instead of `zip` since Array has an `Int` zero-based indices)

---

EDIT: `Dictionary(_:uniquingKeysWith:)` approach (@Jessy's answer) is a cleaner way to do it

Comment: Downvoted because it's reinventing the `uniquingKeysWith` wheel. 

Comment: @Jessy, yeah, `uniquingKeysWith` would have worked too...

Answer (score 2):

New Dev's answer is the way to go. Except, the standard library already has a solution that does that, so use that instead.

```swift
Dictionary(
  ["john", "john", "blake", "robert", "john", "blake"]
    .enumerated()
    .map { ($0.element, $0.offset) }
) { $1 }
```

Or if you've already got a collection elsewhere…

```swift
Dictionary(zip(collection, collection.indices)) { $1 }
```

Comment: `enumerated` returns an offset - not an index. It would work for an array, sure, but it's not a one-size-fits-all way to get an index

Comment: The question is about `Array`.

Comment: @NewDev `enumerated` called on an array returns `EnumeratedSequence` where the *offset* is always an `Int`, in practice an *index*.

Comment: I know - I commented as much... but my comment was in reference to it being the "way to do it"... - it works, for a special case of an array, but I wouldn't have called it the built-in way

Comment: Edited to account for whateva `Collection`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, the one-liner, and likely the shortest, solution (brevity over clarity, or was it the other way around? :P)

```swift
myArray.enumerated().reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.0] = $1.1 }
```